# Qt / QML - Choose how many characters to be displayed in a Text item

Tags: qt, qml

I would like to display only the two first characters of a word in a Text item.
For example, I have a list of words (FRENCH, ENGLISH, ITALIAN) and I would like to display only (FR, EN, IT).

If I elide the text, I will always get three dots (...) at the end and I don't want that.

Any ideas ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You don't want to show the first two characters of three words in a text element (FRENCH, ENGLISH, ITALIAN), you want to show simply three different words in a text element (FR, EN, IT). Well, show them. This sounds like an XY-problem.

Comment: Unfortunately my c++ method returns this list of complete words and I just wanted to know if I can just display only two characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set `clip` to `true` but then you would need to play with the `width`.

So I think the best option is to implement a little function in JavaScript to get only the first two letters.

Example:

**main.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.5
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import "myscript.js" as MyFunctions

Window {
    visible: true

    // You need to play with the width
    Text {
        width: 13
        text: "FRENCH"
        clip: true
    }

    // OK. width is not necessary
    Text {
        y: 60
        text: MyFunctions.substring("FRENCH")
    }

    // We don't want this behaviour
    Text {
        y: 30
        width: 25
        text: "FRENCH"
        elide: Text.ElideRight
    }
}
```

**myscript.js**

```
function substring(str) {
    return str.substring(0, 2);
}
```

Comment: Sounds like an idea, I will give a try

Comment: Well, I didn't know about this substring function, it works like charm. Thanks a lot !

Comment: Thanks to you! Happy coding! :)

Answer (score 0):

Do remember that the first letters in country names and the corresponding ISO standard 2- or 3-letter country codes are a different thing. For example, the 2-letter code for Andorra is AD. (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-2) -- So, if you are trying to achieve country ISO standard country coding, you should simply make a list of objects, which have the properties name, isoCode2, and so on, as required, for example:

> property var myArrayOfCountries: [
>
> ```
> { "name" : "Andorra", "isoCode2" : "AD" },
> { "name" : "United Arab Emirates", "isoCode2" : "AE" },
> ...
> ```
>
> ]

I would probably try to get these from some web service, if available, as the creation and maintenance of such list could be a pain.

...That said, if you simply need to get the first two letters from a string in QML Javascript, I would simply use

> text: myString.substring(0, 2)

or perhaps in your case, I presume:

> text: myArrayOfStrings[someIndex].substring(0, 2)

---

Ps., with the object list approach you would use:

> text: myArrayOfCountries[someIndex]["isoCode2"]

of course.